# Alterar ordem de execução de arquivos JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que ao clicar no botão próximo a aplicação ASP.NET WebForms executa um código dinâmico (esse script é construído no carregamento de cada página, Dynamic.JS - ele é traduzido de blocos de programação C#) e depois no mesmo evento deveria chamar as functions referentes no Validacoes.JS.
O único problema está na ordem de execução.
A aplicação chama Validacoes.JS antes de Dynamic.JS e para que a aplicação se comporte como o esperado é necessário que Dynamic.JS seja executado primeiro.
Como faço isso?

OBS:
Chamar uma função dentro da outra não seria uma solução viável para mim. O nome da function associada ao botão próximo varia de página para página no arquivo Dynamic.JS

```
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
// Validacoes.JS ---> No momento é o primeiro a ser executado... deveria ser executado após o Dynamic.JS
// no ProximoButton esse evento verificacaoProximo está no onclick!


function verificacaoProximo() {
    if (retorno == "avanca") {
        if ($("#HiddenFielPodeAvancarTela").val().toString() == "0") { // PodeAvancar NAO
            if ($("#HiddenFielPodeAvancarTelaFlag").val().toString() == "1")
                retorno = "avanca";
            else
                retorno = "naoavanca";
        }
        else { // PodeAvancar SIM
            if ($("#HiddenFielPodeAvancarTelaFlag").val().toString() == "1")
                retorno = "avanca";
            else
                retorno = "naoavanca";
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}




//Dynamic.JS
$(document).ready(function () {

// HiddenField
if (!document.getElementById("hfcerto") ) {
var input792 = document.createElement("input");
input792.setAttribute("type","hidden");
input792.setAttribute("name", "hfcerto");
input792.setAttribute("value", "0");
input792.setAttribute("id", "hfcerto");
document.getElementById("hfs").appendChild(input792);
}

// HiddenField
if (!document.getElementById("hferro") ) {
var input121 = document.createElement("input");
input121.setAttribute("type","hidden");
input121.setAttribute("name", "hferro");
input121.setAttribute("value", "0");
input121.setAttribute("id", "hferro");
document.getElementById("hfs").appendChild(input121);
}



$("#ProximoButton892").click(function(){
    prox_click();
});

});



function prox_click(){
if((document.getElementById("hfcerto").getAttribute("value")=="8")&&(document.getElementById("hferro").getAttribute("value")=="0")){
document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src = document.getElementById("ImageButton2").src;
}
else if((document.getElementById("hfcerto").getAttribute("value")=="5")&&(document.getElementById("hferro").getAttribute("value")=="0")){
document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src = document.getElementById("ImageButton2").src;
}
else {
document.getElementById("ImageButton1").src = document.getElementById("PictureBoxProp891").src;

var valorHF = document.getElementById("HiddenFielQtdExercErrados").getAttribute("value");
document.getElementById("HiddenFielQtdExercErrados").setAttribute("value", parseInt(document.getElementById("HiddenFielQtdExercErrados").getAttribute("value")) + 1);
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Poderia publicar o seu código? Ficaria mais fácil de ajudar assim. (;

Comment: Ajudaria? Lembrando que é dinâmico! Cada tela apresenta códigos diferentes...

Comment: Código publicado @FelipeAvelar

Answer (score 1):

Vou demonstrar com analogia a um problema simples, e veja se com isso consegue resolver o seu problema.

O jQuery tem uma API de interface gráfica, e ela só funciona se o **core** do jQuery já estiver carregado, então quando for chamar a interface, primeiro você chama o core, codificando isso seria algo como

```
<script src="../js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // Primeiro esse
<script src="../js/js_1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js?v=01" type="text/javascript"></script> // depois este
```

Comment: O document.Ready é lido na ordem em que o script é declarado. Isso deu certo. Porém na hora que necessito que ele execute as functions ele não segue a ordem da declaração....

Comment: Comenta em cada linha do seu codigo a ordem que esta sendo executado para eu entender melhor seu caso